# create a global variable chrome app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am creating a Chrome app. this is my manifest file.

```
{
//...... description and other things
//.......
"app": {
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["js/main.js"]
    }
},
// other things
```

}

and in my js/main.js file, I have defined a global variable as globalData.

```
    chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {

  chrome.app.window.create('/dashboard.html', {
    'bounds': {
      'width': screen.availWidth,
      'height': screen.availHeight
    }
  });
});
var globalData;
```

(purpose of doing that I need a variable that available whole runtime).
In dashboar.html I have included services.js files. Is there a way that I can use that globalData variable in services.js.

Answer (score 5):

From any chrome app window you can access the backgroundPage, and thus also access variables assigned to its global object (top level `var` like you have are automatically attached)

Try this:

```
chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(bgpage) {
  console.log(bgpage.globalData);
})
```

You can also save a reference to the background page, or save a reference to the global data object itself (usual javascript caveats apply):

```
// in bgpage
var globalData = {};
globalData.apples = ['red', 'green'];

// in app window
var globalData;
chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(bgpage) {
   globalData = bgpage.globalData;
   main();
})
function main() {
   console.log(globalData.apples);
}
```